How to Prevent Copied Text from Being Stored in the Vim Register Every Time Text is Deleted?
I'm encountering an issue in Vim where every time I delete text, it gets stored in the Vim register, causing it to be pasted again when I use the paste command. This behavior is becoming quite frustrating as it clutters the register with unnecessary text. Is there a way to prevent deleted text from being stored in the register or to clear the register automatically after each deletion? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
In Vim, whenever I delete text, it gets stored in the register, leading to unwanted clutter and repetitive pasting. I've attempted to find a solution by exploring Vim documentation and experimenting with different settings, but haven't had any luck so far. I was expecting there might be a configuration option or a command that I could use to prevent deleted text from being stored in the register, or perhaps a way to automatically clear the register after each deletion. Any guidance on how to achieve this or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Use black hole register "_. For example "_dd  — delete a line into black hole register; the line deleted, all registers stay intact.
